# Переход с WinForms  MVP на Silverlight MVVM

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm

Есть программа, имитирующая работу светофора, написана на Winform с использованием паттерна  MVP. Нужно переделать все на Silverlight под паттерн MVVM. Какие основные различия между MVP и MVVM, какие радикальные изменения нужно сделать в программе  при переходе на Silverlight, какая часть программы (модель, вид или модель вида) должна реализовываться на XAML, а какая на C#? Какие общие пожелания можете дать   по этому поводу и какие статьи желательно прочитать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Про отличия:

[Паттерны: MVC, MVP и MVVM](http://outcoldman.com/ru/blog/show/184) -- для ознакомления

[Приложения WPF с шаблоном проектирования модель-представление-модель представления](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/dd419663.aspx) -- более подробно

Если кратко, то одно из главных отличий MVVM от MVP в том, что ViewModel не нуждается в ссылке на View, в отличие от Presenter'а. Соответственно с этим будут связаны ваши основные переделки.

На XAML пишется View. На C# - Model и ViewModel.

Comment: Впринципе, я давненько уже разобрался с этим, но остался такой вот вопрос: в MVP для каждой View нужен свой Presenter?

Comment: В классическом варианте — да. Как и в MVVM.